# How to prevent GWT from obfuscating code/Where to find the GWT Compiler

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, gwt

I am currently working to find a bug in my code, and upon inspecting element on my browser (FF and GC), I found that the java source code is obfuscated by GWT in order to increase parse speed. From researching online, i found that:

> If you prefer not to have GWT obfuscate its output, then you can use
>   the -style flag on the GWT Compiler. This flag has one of three
>   possible values:
>
> OBF (for obfuscated), the default
>   PRETTY, which makes the output readable to a human
>   DETAILED, which improves on PRETTY with even
>   more detail (such as very verbose variable names)

I am wondering where I can find the GWT compiler.

Comment: Look at GWT Compiler Options on http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html

Comment: Are you using eclipse or trying to compile from command line ?

Comment: @Raj I am trying to compile from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standalone compiler executable for GWT, it comes as part of GWT SDK. Download the GWT SDK and from within the SDK dir you can invoke GWT compiler.

Check this link - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions

I have highlighted the style option.
[image]